# DBCC IND not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dbcc

I'm trying to get the pages used by a clustered index on table1 in a SQL2008 R2 DEV box using the below query.

```
dbcc traceon(3604, -1) 
go 
dbcc ind (0, 'dbo.table1', 1) 
go
```

but it still displays the below output and doesn't display the results.What am i doing wrong here?

[image]

Also the below message is logged in the SQL server log

> Message DBCC TRACEON 3604, server process ID (SPID) 59. This is an
>   informational message only; no user action is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue and this might be one of the reason for no result.

**Cause:**

When you create a table and when no record is present in the table and you run `dbcc ind` on such table then you get the "message like below but NO tabular result".

> DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

If table on other hand has records you would get tabular output.

For more understanding I suggest you read following blogs from Paul Randal

- [More about undocumented Command DBCC IND](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2006/12/13/more-undocumented-fun-dbcc-ind-dbcc-page-and-off-row-columns/)
- [How to use DBCC IND command to find out various internal SQL Server information](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-using-dbcc-page-and-dbcc-ind-to-find-out-if-page-splits-ever-roll-back/)

These blogs would help you in understanding how to use DBCC IND to get various information from database and how to interpret the result.